# My Div is just overlapping another div whereas i am putting it after the first div

Tags: html, css

I have made 1 header and 2 divs. Out of which one div (The second and the lower div) is just overlapping the other. I need help solving this problem.

Here is the code. (It is big so i have hastebinned them)-

1) [HTML](https://hastebin.com/ihareragib.xml)
2) [CSS](https://hastebin.com/igekewikuk.css)

Please help me.

I have already tried using using 
`clear: both`, 
`overflow: hidden`
And those don't work. Also I have checked that I have closed each and every div.

I have expected the div 3 to end appear after div3. I guess the problem is that i have just used margins but i am not sure.

Comment: Please share only the relevant code. Not all the code you have. Nobody will stay and triage that code. Just make a working snippet that has the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Welcome to the stack overflow. Please post the relevant code so we can help you out

Answer (score -1):

Please check the [codepen](https://codepen.io/soniaj204/pen/zVNByG). It seems you have added absolute css property which is not required in your case and unwanted padding/margin.

Updated code below as:

```
    #division2{
        background-color: white;
    /*     padding-top: 3%;
        padding-left: 5%;
        padding-right: 5%; 
        padding-bottom: 3%;  
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 4%;
        margin-bottom: 4%;
        margin-right: 10%;
        margin-left: 10%; */
        color: #555;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        clear: both;
        overflow: hidden;
    /* display: inline; */
}
```

Comment: I fixed it (I had posted another problem which i have fixed)